# R Exponent Produces NaN

Tags: r, math, exponent

I am running into an issue when I exponentiate floating point data. It seems like it should be an easy fix. Here is my sample code:

```
temp <- c(-0.005220092)
temp^1.1

[1] NaN

-0.005220092^1.1

[1] -0.003086356
```

Is there some obvious error I am making with this? It seems like it might be an oversight on my part with regard to exponents.

Thanks,

Alex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for the NaN is because the result of the exponentiation is complex, so you have to pass a complex argument:

```
as.complex(temp)^1.1
[1] -0.002935299-0.000953736i
# or
(temp + 0i)^1.1
[1] -0.002935299-0.000953736i
```

The reason that your second expression works is because unary `-` has lower precedence than `^`, so this is equivalent to `-(0.005220092^1.1)`. See `?Syntax`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That clears that up, I appreciate the quick response.

Comment: @RHertel very nice catch!