# R exponentiating mystery

Tags: r

Does anyone have any idea why the following produced a NaN? I am running this on R 4.0.2 on OSX.

```
> (1.55e-04/-7.35e-05)^(10/(22.77-12.66))
[1] NaN
```

If I break it down, I also get a NaN

```
> a <- (1.55e-04/-7.35e-05)
> b <- (10/(22.77-12.66))
> a^b
[1] NaN
```

But, if I just put in the numbers, I get the correct answer...

```
> a
[1] -2.108844
> b
[1] 0.9891197
> -2.108844 ^ 0.9891197
[1] -2.091793
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R Exponent Produces NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36348409/r-exponent-produces-nan)

Comment: sign(a)*abs(a)^b works

Comment: It might not produce an error, but you're not making the calculation you want with that. You're doing `abs(a)^b`, than making that result negative. In order to do the calculation you want, you need to work with complex numbers.

Comment: For the data I am working with, it is the correct calculation.

Comment: basically the same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63005466/is-the-order-of-operations-different-within-functions-than-without/63005573#63005573 ... you probably want `-(2.108844 ^ 0.9891197)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Do* you get the correct answer though? The following works:

```r
-2.108844 ^ 0.9891197
#> [1] -2.091793
```

And gives the same result as the following:

```
-(2.108844 ^ 0.9891197)
#> [1] -2.091793
```

But look what happens if I move the negative sign inside the brackets:

```
(-2.108844) ^ 0.9891197
#> [1] NaN
```

Note that R quite appropriately gives `NaN` because I am raising a negative number to a fractional power.

So the answer to your question is that due to operator precedence, the R parser is interpreting

```
-2.108844 ^ 0.9891197
```

as

```r
-(2.108844 ^ 0.9891197)
```

Which is giving you the wrong answer when you type the numbers directly.

Answer (score 1):

You are taking the root of a negative number, so your result is complex, you can't treat it as *normal* numeric, you need to:

```
a <- (1.55e-04/-7.35e-05)
b <- (10/(22.77-12.66))
as.complex(a)^as.complex(b)
```

Output:

```
-0.1487035-0.6348101i
```

Possible duplicate of [R Exponent Produces NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36348409/r-exponent-produces-nan)